# Lookahead in C/Reading

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, user-input, scanf

I wrote this code, as a sort of lookahead.

```
int main() {
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    scanf("%s", a);
    if (a[0] == '@') {
        scanf("{%s}", b);
    }
    printf("%s\n", b);
}
```

For some reason, I get a segfault after hitting enter the first time, my input was `@hi`. What's going on?

Comment: The error you made here is the same as the one here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466297/printf-limited-to-three-characters) - You're overwriting a globally-stored string that is only 1 character long.

Comment: *Sigh* I swear, 50% of all rep comes from these questions.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's wrong in the linked question... o.O

Comment: @quasiverse: Hence why I'm gonna start sitting these out.

Comment: Okay, just fixed that. Removed the assignment. Still segfaults.

Comment: The error is this `char *a = "0";` You're assigning a globally-stored string of length 2 into `a`. When you overwrite it with `scanf` you write 4 characters (including the NULL).

Comment: @Mysticial I removed the assignment

Comment: Try this: `char a[100];` and `char b[100];`.

Comment: @tekknolagi Now you're creating a char pointer that doesn't point *anywhere*. That's even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your first piece of code (before the edit) was that you were creating a string storing 2 characters. The '0' and the NULL. You then try to overwrite this with 4 characters from `scanf`.

In the second piece of code, you're not pointing the char pointer *anywhere*. You just declared it without giving it a value so it could be pointing to anything.

To get the behaviour you want you need to create an array of chars like this:

```
char a[100];
char b[100];
```

You'll have to make the array big enough for your purposes.

Also, if you want to read the two strings in, you'll have to "consume" the white space between them. To do this, change the second `scanf` to:

```
scanf(" {%s}", b);
```

Note the space before the `{`.

Comment: I did that, and now when i `scanf` the result for `b` is complete gibberish.

Comment: @tekknolagi What did you type in?

Comment: @tekknolagi Instead of `scanf("{%s}", ...)` try `scanf(" {%s}", ...)`. Note the space.

Comment: oh... right. how can i make it skip over all whitespace though?

Comment: @tekknolagi What do you mean? That does skip over all the whitespace.

Comment: What if i have tabs and newlines separating them...?

Comment: Why does the space make all the difference? And why, if i enter `@hi {lol}` does it print `lol}`?

Comment: @tekknolagi The space represents any whitespace character and the really you get `lol}` is that in your `scanf`. It sees `{` so it ignores it in the input and then gets a string. Then it sees `}` but it's already taken that in as part of the string so nothing happens.

Comment: How would I go about getting multiple words into a string? like if i want to have `{ sentence0 ; sentence1 ; sentence2 }`...for some reason it only sees the first "word"

Comment: @tekknolagi Strings are separated by spaces. I really can't keep going through these comments. If you want further help you can always ask a new question or search it up.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", a);`, per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), tries to store a string (`%s`) in the locations pointed to by the pointer arguments that follow format (`a`). In this case, `a` is uninitialized and does not point to any storage space. To read a single character, consider this example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char c;


    /* among other things, read a character */
    scanf("%c", &c);

    return 0;
}
```

expand on it to get the intended behaviour. Additionally, I would advise you to steer clear of `scanf`, and do your matching yourself while reading with `fgets`.